# How to loop the acf repeater when row count is 3

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Hi guys can you help me to fix my issue?
Basically, I added a div to my acf repeater items but I need 3 items per div

My issue is that the div that is looping is inside the div as well.

e.g
Row 1 (1, 2 ,3), Row 2 (1, 2 ,3)

```
    <?php

    $course_reference = get_field('course-reference-number');
    $program_id = get_field('course-program-id');

    if( have_rows('course_month_out') ):
       while( have_rows('course_month_out') ) : the_row();

             if( have_rows('course_schedule_row_dates') ):
                $count = 0;
                $group = 0;

                while( have_rows('course_schedule_row_dates') ) : the_row();
                    
                $course_date_selector = get_sub_field('course_date_selector');
                $course_date_url = date('d-m-y',strtotime($course_date_selector));
                $current_date_field = get_sub_field('course_date_selector', false, false);
                $currentDateTime = date('Ymd');
           
                
                if ($count % 3 == 0) {
                 
                    ?>
                        <div class="course_block">
                    <?php 
                }
                $group++;
                ?>

                <?php
                if($current_date_field < $currentDateTime) {
                
                }
                else {
                    ?>
                    <?php if(get_row_index() > 1 ){  echo ",";}?>
                    <a href="<?php echo 'https://ei.aimsapp.com/onlineapp/LandingPage.aspx?strProgID=' .  $program_id  . "&strIntakeID=" . $course_date_url . "-". $course_reference . "-01"  ?> " target="_blank"> <?php echo $course_date_selector; ?></a>
                
                    <?php 
                }
                ?>
              <?php       
            if ($count % 3 == 2) {
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
            }
            $count++;
        endwhile;
         
            endwhile;
        endif;
    endwhile;
    endif;

    ?>
```

Here's the expected output:

[image]

Comment: Stuff like this is way easier, if you output the first opening tag before the loop, and the last closing one after. And then inside, when your counter is > 0 and % 3 == 0, you simply output `</div> <div class="course_block">`first.

Comment: Hi @CBroe can you give me an example of what you mean so I can try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I've tidied up your code, fixed errors and it should work. Saying that it's hard to test ACFs scripts without using the original environment

```
<?php

$course_reference = get_field('course-reference-number');
$program_id = get_field('course-program-id');

if( have_rows('course_month_out') ):
    
    while( have_rows('course_month_out') ) : the_row();
        
        if( have_rows('course_schedule_row_dates') ):
            
            $count = 0;
            $group = 0;

            while( have_rows('course_schedule_row_dates') ) : the_row();
                
                $course_date_selector = get_sub_field('course_date_selector');
                $course_date_url = date('d-m-y',strtotime($course_date_selector));
                $current_date_field = get_sub_field('course_date_selector', false, false);
                $currentDateTime = date('Ymd');
           
                // if it's 1/3
                if ($count % 3 == 0) {
                    
                    //open div
                    $html = '<div class="course_block">';
                    $group++;
                            
                }

                if($current_date_field < $currentDateTime) {
                    
                    //something
                
                } else {
                   
                    if( get_row_index() > 1 ){
                        
                        echo ",";
                        
                    }
                    
                    $html .= '<a href="https://ei.aimsapp.com/onlineapp/LandingPage.aspx?strProgID=' .  $program_id  . '&strIntakeID=' . $course_date_url . '-'. $course_reference . '-01" target="_blank">' . $course_date_selector . '</a>';
                    
                }
            
                // if it's 3/3
                if ($count % 3 == 1) {
     
                    $html .= '</div>';
                  
                }
                
                $count++;
        
            endwhile;
        endif;
    endwhile;
    
    echo $html;
    
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, basically this is something I need to achieve https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/insert-in-between-repeater-fields/